# Show $\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}/n$ converges in probability to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

> Suppose $X_n\geq0$ are any sequence of random variables and $\dfrac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}\stackrel{p}{\to}1$. Then show that $\dfrac{\max(X_1,...,X_n)}{n}\stackrel{p}{\to}0$ and for any $r>1$, $\dfrac{1}{n^r}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^r\stackrel{p}{\to}0$.

I could prove the almost sure version of this, that is, replacing convergence in probability by almost sure convergence everywhere in the statement. I thought of a subsequence argument (first showing for a subsequence that almost surely the results hold) but things don't seem to go through.

I have obtained that $X_n/n$ converges in probability to $0$. If this was an almost sure statement then I could immediately say that this implies $\max(X_1,...,X_n)/n$ also converges almost surely to $0$.

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3390404/36150) (without an answer)

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The convergence of the maximum $M_n:=n^{-1}\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k$ was treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390404/convergence-of-series-in-probability-to-1-implies-convergence-of-pointwise-max-o/3495509#3495509). Observe that for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$,  $X_k\leqslant nM_n$ hence $X_k^{r-1}\leqslant n^{r-1}M_n^{r-1}$; this leads to the bound
$$
0\leqslant\dfrac{1}{n^r}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^r\leqslant \frac 1{n^r}\sum_{k=1}^n X_kn^{r-1}M_n^{r-1}=\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_k\right)M_n^{r-1}.
$$
The first factor converges in probability to one, the second one in probability to $0$ since $r-1>0$.