# How to show that a sequence of non-negative random variables cezaro summable to $1$ in probability has its partial maxima series of order $o(n)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $\left\{X_n \right\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables with $\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} 1$. How to show that $\dfrac{1}{n} \max_{i=1}^n X_i \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} 0$?.

I can easily show this for constant sequence and hence the above statement if convergence in probability is replaced by almost sure convergence (in both convergences). But I am stuck with showing convergence in probability.

For constant sequence the proof goes in this way. $\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \longrightarrow 1$ implies that $x_n/n \longrightarrow 0$. On the otherhand, consider the subsequence $\left\{n_l\right\}_{l \geq 1}$ as follows. Set $n_0=0$ and $n_l := \inf \left\{ k > n_{l-1} \mid x_k > \max_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i \right\}$, for $l \geq 1$. If $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \max_{i=1}^n x_i >0$, then it is easy to see that $ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \max_{i=1}^n x_i = \lim_{l \to \infty} x_{n_l}/n_l$. But the latter term is zero from our hypothesis. This gives a contradiction.

Comment: If you can show convergence almost surely you are done because it implies convergence in probability. Not sure if I misunderstood your comment though.

Comment: I meant to say you can easily prove the maxima scaled by $n$ converges to $0$ almost surely if the average converges almost surely. But that argument does not work if we only have the average converging in probability.

Comment: This problem has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390404/convergence-of-series-in-probability-to-1-implies-convergence-of-pointwise-max-o/3495509#3495509

Comment: @LostStatistician18 I tried to follow the proof in the answer you referred to. In the proof of the lemma therein, there is an assertion $m_l > n_{a,l}$ for all $a$, which I think is not true. The correct assertion will be $m_l > n_{a,l}$ for all $1 \leq a \leq l$, I think the proof breaks down because of this. You only get to prove $ \sup_{1 \leq a \leq l} |\dfrac{S_{am_l}}{am_l} -1| $  converges to $0$ almost surely as $l \to \infty$, which is not sufficient for the next part to go through.